# How to use an enhanced enum for storing different units of measurement with the ability to parse

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I have a class & enum that looks like this

```dart
enum UnitsOfMeasurement {
  meters,
  feet,
  inches,
  centimeters,
  millimeters,
}

class MyMaterial {
  final double height;
  final UnitsOfMeasurement unitOfMeasurement;
  MyMaterial({required this.height, required this.unitOfMeasurement});
}
```

The user can change the unit of measurment and then when I display the height I have utility functions to parse from and to each unit of measurment (from meters to inches, from inches to feet, etc..).

I would like to see if it's possible to include this logic into the enum, or if there is some other better method than having multiple utility functions to handle this logic.

Comment: Just use an enum with a property double numOfMeters, and then you can convert each pair of values to meters, then back to the destination.  Y'all are working too hard from the answers I've seen so far.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, I thought I understood your take on it. But didn't see how it would make the total number of conversion options that much simpler than a mapping table. Feel free to present your solution with code.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz That would work but it is an extra step. I have no guarantee what the units of measurement the BLE device will give me. So it's pretty nice to just parse to whatever I want instead of having to parse to meters and then to whatever the desired units of measurement are.

Comment: Ah, okey, now I understood you. Adding that option to my answer. Very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit (cred to Randal):

```
enum UnitsOfMeasurement {
  meters(1),
  feet(3.28),
  inches(39.3700787402),
  centimeters(100),
  millimeters(1000);

  const UnitsOfMeasurement(this.inMeters);
  final double inMeters;

  double convert(double value, UnitsOfMeasurement to) => value / inMeters * to.inMeters;
}
```

Used as:

```
print(UnitsOfMeasurement.inches.convert(42, UnitsOfMeasurement.millimeters));
```

Or in terms of the `MyMaterial` class:

```
class MyMaterial {
  final double height;
  final UnitsOfMeasurement unitOfMeasurement;
  MyMaterial({required this.height, required this.unitOfMeasurement});

  double convert(UnitsOfMeasurement to) => unitOfMeasurement.convert(height, to);
```

### Original answer:

You don't need multiple utility functions. One mapping/factor table and one method/function is enough. Place the method and table at a point of your liking.

There are a few way to do this. I don't think using enhanced enums is the cleanest approach. I think the cleanest approach is a translation/mapping/factor table and a simple method in the `MyMaterial` class. This is shown last of the examples.

### Enhanced enum way:

```
enum UnitsOfMeasurement {
  meters,
  feet,
  inches,
  centimeters,
  millimeters;

  double convert(double value, UnitsOfMeasurement to) => value * factors[this]![to]!;
}
```

### Extension method on enum way:

```
extension UnitsOfMeasurementX on UnitsOfMeasurement {
  double convertX(double value, UnitsOfMeasurement to) {
    return value * factors[this]![to]!;
  }
}
```

### Simple method on MyMaterial:

```
class MyMaterial {
  final double height;
  final UnitsOfMeasurement unitOfMeasurement;
  MyMaterial({required this.height, required this.unitOfMeasurement});

  double convert(UnitsOfMeasurement to) => height * factors[unitOfMeasurement]![to]!;
}
```

You could obviously use the enhanced enum method, or the extension method inside the `MyMaterial` class method if you don't like to have the conversion logic stored in the `MyMaterial` class. Then you would just do this in the `MyMaterial` method:

```
double convert(UnitsOfMeasurement to) => unitOfMeasurement.convert(height, to);
```

### Mapping/Factor logic:

All options use a factor mapping that looks like this. Not completed though, that is for the OP to add :) :

```
const factors = <UnitsOfMeasurement, Map<UnitsOfMeasurement, double>>{
  UnitsOfMeasurement.meters: {
    UnitsOfMeasurement.meters: 1,
    UnitsOfMeasurement.millimeters: 1000,
    UnitsOfMeasurement.centimeters: 100,
    UnitsOfMeasurement.inches: 39.3700787402,
    UnitsOfMeasurement.feet: 3.28084,
  },
  UnitsOfMeasurement.feet: {
    UnitsOfMeasurement.feet: 1,
    UnitsOfMeasurement.meters: 1 / 3.28084,
  },
  UnitsOfMeasurement.inches: {
    UnitsOfMeasurement.inches: 1,
    UnitsOfMeasurement.meters: 1 / 39.3700787402,
  },
  UnitsOfMeasurement.centimeters: {
    UnitsOfMeasurement.centimeters: 1,
    UnitsOfMeasurement.meters: 1 / 100,
  },
  UnitsOfMeasurement.millimeters: {
    UnitsOfMeasurement.millimeters: 1,
    UnitsOfMeasurement.meters: 1 / 1000,
  },
};
```

### Used like this:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final material = MyMaterial(
    height: 2,
    unitOfMeasurement: UnitsOfMeasurement.meters,
  );

  print(material.convert(UnitsOfMeasurement.feet));
  print(material.unitOfMeasurement.convert(material.height, UnitsOfMeasurement.feet));
  print(material.unitOfMeasurement.convertX(material.height, UnitsOfMeasurement.feet));

  final enhancedEnum = UnitsOfMeasurement.meters;
  print(enhancedEnum.convert(2, UnitsOfMeasurement.feet));

  final extensionEnum = UnitsOfMeasurement.meters;
  print(extensionEnum.convertX(2, UnitsOfMeasurement.feet));
}
```

### DartPad with all the code:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=2f750de1fbc1da5b39555248e24c6c04

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Really appreciate you going above and beyond on your example.

Answer (score -1):

Add a customized getter method inside the class

```
enum UnitsOfMeasurement {
  meters,
  feet,
  inches,
  centimeters,
  millimeters,
}

class MyMaterial {
  final double height;
  final UnitsOfMeasurement unitOfMeasurement;
  MyMaterial({required this.height, required this.unitOfMeasurement});
  
  double get convertedHeight{
    switch(unitOfMeasurement){
      case UnitsOfMeasurement.meters:  return 1.0; //change the logic;
      case UnitsOfMeasurement.feet:  return 1.0; //change the logic;
      case UnitsOfMeasurement.inches:  return 1.0; //change the logic;
      case UnitsOfMeasurement.centimeters:  return 1.0; //change the logic;
      case UnitsOfMeasurement.millimeters:  return 1.0; //change the logic;
      default:  return 1.0; //change the logic;
    }
  }
}
```

now call the `convertedHeight` like this:

```
MyMaterial(height: 10, unitOfMeasurement: UnitsOfMeasurement.inches).convertedHeight;
```

Comment: My only issue with this is It can't be just one switch case because I'd need to cover parsing from and to each possible enum value, and I'd also need to pass the UnitsOfMeasurement that I want to parse TO as a parameter.

convertHeight will need to know what the current unitOfMeasurement is, which it does, but it will also need to know what to convert the height to.